# Denoting an argument-dependent range (co-domain) of a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation, type-theory

I would like to define a function whose co-domain depends on its argument, i.e. $\forall x \in X\colon f(x) \in A[x]$ where $X$ is the domain of $f$ and $A[x]$ is the value of a set-valued function. A simple actual example would be a function $I(n)$ that yields an $n$-dimensional vector of ones for each natural number $n$.

The usual workaround that I've seen (in economics) involves something like this:

> $f\colon X \rightarrow \bigcup_{x \in X} A[x]$ where for each $x \in X$, $f(x) \in A[x]$;

or, for the example above,

> $I(n)\colon \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}^n$ where for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $I(n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$; $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers and $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers.

However, that is quite cumbersome. Isn't there some more concise notation for this kind of cases, e.g. $f\colon \lbrace x \in X \rbrace \rightarrow A[x]$? (Thus, for $I(n)$ one would have $I\colon \lbrace n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.)

As somewhat of a spinoff, it would similarly be handier to write, e.g., $\lbrace x \in X \rbrace \times A[x]$ for the set $\lbrace (x, a) \,|\, x \in X,\, a \in A[x] \rbrace$.

P.S.: As I've found out from [this answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3345490/650351) and from [this article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type#%7F%27%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000016-QINU%60%22%27%7F_type), there are such things as $\Pi$-types and $\Sigma$-types which seem to do exactly what I mean. However, I'm not quite sure how to use those as the terminology used in most other sources I've checked is way too foreign for me. So, in simple terms, am I correct to write, respectively, $f \in \prod_{x \in X} A[x]$ and $I \in \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}^n$ for the $f(x)$ and $I(n)$ mentioned above? And is then $\lbrace (x, a) \,|\, x \in X,\, a \in A[x] \rbrace$ the same as $\sum_{x \in X}A[x]$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. These are called *dependent types*. One more side note: in type theory the symbol $\in$ is replaced to colon ($:$), so we write $f:\prod_{x:X}A[x]$.

Comment: @Berci, is the colon from type theory equivalent in meaning to the $\in$ symbol? As I am writing a paper for economists, I would rather not switch to less familiar notation unless it represents something different.

Comment: Yes, basically the same meaning.

Comment: Great, thank you so much @Berci!

Comment: The "workaround" you describe is the standard definition for an indexed cartesian product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_Cartesian_products. Which are essentially the set theoretic implementation of dependent functions/$\Pi$-types